# Way to classify extrema in multivariable calculus

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

I am not getting the way to classify the extrema of my booklet.... Can anyone explain the process of my booklet solution which is in second image.. ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ystJ7.jpg)

[[][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9P44.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9P44.jpg)

Comment: If you type out the content of those images and format them nicely (i.e. using [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)), you'll be much more likely to get helpful answers. Leaving your question like this makes it very likely it'll be ignored.

Comment: I always type my question. But at present i don't have that time for typing so i uploaded image of it.. sorry for inconvenience